# Issue Generating ObjectFactory.java and package-info.java with jaxb2-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb, code-generation

I am currently facing an issue while using the jaxb2-maven-plugin to generate Java classes from an XSD in my Maven project. The problem is that the ObjectFactory and package-info.java classes are not being generated as expected. I have followed the recommended steps and checked various configurations, but the issue persists.

Here are the details of my setup:
I am using the jaxb2-maven-plugin with version 2.5.0.
My XSD file is well-formed and follows the expected structure.
The Maven plugin configuration in my pom.xml seems correct.
I have validated my project's Maven and Java versions for compatibility.

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or solutions that can help me resolve this issue. If you have encountered a similar problem with the jaxb2-maven-plugin or have expertise in JAXB code generation, please share your thoughts on what might be causing this issue and how to fix it.

Checked the Maven plugin configuration.
Cleaned the project using mvn clean.
Inspected the generated Java classes to ensure they match the XSD structure.